# Javascript Code is not running, even an alert at the very top isnt triggering

Tags: javascript

I am new here but my code is not working at all, it even has an alert on the first line that isn't triggering. I looked and could not find any errors. Help? Also, my array randomizer is not working, it just gives me the string "laarvite" all of the time. I would like a fix to that if possible.

```
alert("Welcome to our currently unnamed online card game!")
var keepPlay = true // variables 
var dmg11 = 0
var dmg12 = 0
var dmg21 = 0
var dmg22 = 0
var hp1 = 1
var hp2 = 1
var def1 = 1
var def2 = 1
var playerElement1 = 5
var playerElement2 = 5
var move1p1 = "none"
var move2p1 = "none"
var move1p2 = "none"
var move2p2 = "none"
var elementUse11 = 0
var elementUse21 = 0
var elementUse12 = 0
var elementUse22 = 0
var dmgmult11 = 1
var dmgmult21 = 1
var dmgmult12 = 1
var dmgmult22 = 1
var cooldownLate1 = 0
var cooldownLate2 = 0
var cooldownp1 = 0
var cooldownp2 = 0
var recoil11 = 0
var recoil21 = 0
var recoil12 = 0
var recoil22 = 0
    while (keepPlay = true) { // if variable stays true, then this will keep looping.
        var monsterArray = ["Laarvite", "Flortite", "Concursores"] // an arry with all of the monster names.
        var playerMonster1 = monsterArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * monsterArray.length)]; //chooses random monster from array
        var playerMonster2 = monsterArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * monsterArray.length)];
                if ("Laarvite" = playerMonster1) {  // monster stat database
                    hp1 = 25
                    def1 = 40
                    move1p1 = "Gnaw"
                    move2p1 = "Repopulate"
                    alert("Player One has drawn Laarvite!")
                } else if ("Flortite" = playerMonster1) {
                    def1 = 35
                    def1 = 35
                    move1p1 = "Ramming Force"
                    move2p1 = "Wrath"
                    alert("Player One has drawn Flortite!")
                } else if ("Concursores" = playerMonster1) {
                    hp1 = 50
                    def1 = 60
                    move1p1 = "Shock"
                    move2p1 = "Electric Laser"
                    alert("Player One has drawn Concusores!")
                }
                        if ("Laarvite" = playerMonster2) { 
                            hp2 = 25
                            def2 = 40
                            move1p2 = "Gnaw"
                            move2p2 = "Repopulate"
                            alert("Player Two has drawn Laarvite!")
                        } else if ("Flortite" = playerMonster2) {
                            hp2 = 35
                            def2 = 35
                            move1p2 = "Ramming Force"
                            move2p2 = "Wrath"
                            alert("Player Two has drawn Flortite!")
                        } else if ("Concursores" = playerMonster2) {
                            hp2 = 50
                            def2 = 60
                            move1p2 = "Shock"
                            move2p2 = "Electric Laser"
                            alert("Player One has drawn Concusores!")
                        }
            if (move1p1 = "Gnaw") { //monster move database
                dmg11 = 10;
                elementUse11 = 3;
            } else if (move1p1 = "Ramming Force") {
                cooldownLate2 = 3;
                dmg11 = 40;
                recoil11 = 2;
                elementUse11 = 4;
            } else if (move1p1 = "Shock") {
                elementUse11 = 1
                dmg11 = 5
            }




            if (move2p1 = "Repopulate") {
                dmgmult21 = 3;
                elementUse21 = 6;
            } else if (move2p1 = "Wrath") {
                dmgmult21 = 2;
                elementUse21 = 3;
            } else if (move2p1 = "Electric Laser") {
                dmgmult21 = 2
                elementUse21 = 2
                dmg21 = 15
            }




            if (move1p2 = "Ramming Force") {
                cooldownLate2 = 3;
                dmg12 = 40;
                recoil21 = 2;
                elementUse12 = 4;
            } else if (move1p2 = "Gnaw") {
                dmg12 = 10;
                elementUse12 = 3;
            } else if (move1p2 = "Shock") {
                elementUse12 = 1
                dmg12 = 5
            }




            if (move2p2 = "Wrath") {
                dmgmult22 = 2;
                elementUse22 = 3;
            } else if (move2p2 = "Repopulate") {
                dmgmult22 = 3;
                elementUse22 = 6;   
            } else if (move2p2 = "Electric Laser") {
                dmgmult22 = 2
                elementUse22 = 2
                dmg22 = 15



            var attackPrompt = prompt("PLAYER 1: Attack with " + move1p1 + " or " + move2p1 + " ? You have " + playerElement1 + " Element points.")
    if (move1p1 === attackPrompt) { // Move 1 Player 1 check
        if (cooldownp1 === 0) { // checks cooldown
            if (elementUse11 <= playerElement1) { // checks if you have enough element to attack
                playerElement1 = playerElement1 - elementUse11; // takes away the element used from your element pool
                if (def2 < dmg11) { // checks if defense is bigger than damage
                    def1 = dmg11; // if so, it makes damage eqaul defense
                    alert("The opponent's defense caused your attack to be weakened!") //message pops up
                    dmg11 = dmg11 * dmgmult11; // takes damage multiplier and multiplies it
                        if (dmgmult11 > 1) { // checks if dmg mult is bigger than one
                            alert("Your damage has been multiplied by " + dmgmult11 + "!") // tells you how much your dmg has been multiplied
                        }
                        hp2 = hp2 - dmg11; //takes health of opponent and subtracts the damage.
                        alert("You have done " + dmg11 + " damage to your opponent, leaving it with " + hp2 + " health remaining.")
                    cooldownp1 = cooldownLate1 + cooldownp1; // checks if attack has cooldown, if so, adds it so you can use moves for however long.
                        if (cooldown > 0) { // checks if coodown is bigger than 0
                            alert("You now have to wait " + cooldownp1 + " turns to attack!") // tells you that you now need however many turns before you can attack
                        } else {

                        }
                    hp1 = hp1 - recoil11; // removes recoil from your health
                        if (hp2 < 1) { // checks if Hp2 (opponents HP) is less than one (dead)
                            alert("You have defeated your opponent!") // states that you have won.
                        } else if (hp1 < 0) { // checks if you have lost all health
                            alert("You have defeated yourself!") // tells you that you are dead.
                        } else if (hp1 !== 0) (hp2 !== 0); { // checks if both you and your enemy are alive.
                            alert("You are still alive with " + hp1 + " health remaining, as with " + hp2 + " remaining for your opponent.") // tells you that you are both alive, with health.
                        }
                } else { // same thing just no def thing
                    dmg11 = dmg11 * dmgmult11; // takes damage multiplier and multiplies it
                        if (dmgmult11 > 1) { // checks if dmg mult is bigger than one
                            alert("Your damage has been multiplied by " + dmgmult11 + "!") // tells you how much your dmg has been multiplied
                        }
                        hp2 = hp2 - dmg11; //takes health of opponent and subtracts the damage.
                        alert("You have done " + dmg11 + " damage to your opponent, leaving it with " + hp2 + " health remaining.")
                    cooldownp1 = cooldownLate1 + cooldownp1; // checks if attack has cooldown, if so, adds it so you can use moves for however long.
                        if (cooldown > 0) { // checks if coodown is bigger than 0
                            alert("You now have to wait " + cooldownp1 + " turns to attack!") // tells you that you now need however many turns before you can attack
                        } else {

                        }
                    hp1 = hp1 - recoil11; // removes recoil from your health
                        if (hp2 < 1) { // checks if Hp2 (opponents HP) is less than one (dead)
                            alert("You have defeated your opponent!") // states that you have won.
                        } else if (hp1 < 0) { // checks if you have lost all health
                            alert("You have defeated yourself!") // tells you that you are dead.
                        } else if (hp1 !== 0) (hp2 !== 0); { // checks if both you and your enemy are alive.
                            alert("You are still alive with " + hp1 + " health remaining, as with " + hp2 + " remaining for your opponent.") // tells you that you are both alive, with health.
                        }
                }
            } else {
                alert("You do not have enough Element for this attack! You need " + playerElement1 + " element in order to use this move.") // shown if you do not have enough element
            }
        } else {
            alert("You need to wait " + cooldownp1 + " turns in order to attack!") // shown if you still have to wait for cooldown to tick
            cooldownp1 - 1; //removes one point from cooldown.
        }
    } else if (attackPrompt === move2p1); { // Move 2 Player 1 check

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you included Script?

Comment: Your `while` and `if` `else` shoud have `==` instead of `=`

Comment: you could use arrays for the same iterable content. further more, you could use objects to store grouped content.

Comment: How are you adding this script to the page? Is it in a separate file or it's inside the HTML document?

Comment: Check the meaning and difference of = == & ===, for compare most times you want the triple equal ===.

Comment: I am implementing it via an HTML page

Comment: Okay, can you post it?

Comment: <html>
<script language="javascript" src="MonsterFight.js" />
<script language="javascript">
f();
</script>
</html>

Comment: New issue: now it is choosing 4 "characters" instead of 2. Halp,

Comment: Try including `<script language="javascript" src="MonsterFight.js"></script>`